# Starlink CONSTELLATION cycle time? Not the orbit time for a specific sat but the time to be over the same spot twice

Tags: artificial-satellite, starlink, satellite-constellation

STARLINK constellation, how many hours for the constellation to cycle? IOWs if a sat is overhead this instant how long till that same sat is over this same spot. The time for the constellation to cycle around the planet... guessing it should be about three days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How close to "this same spot" do you want?  within 5 degrees, 5 arc-seconds, or what?

Comment: one "fat orbit" to the next "fat orbit"